# How to renumber a dataframe according to a periodic and successive column?

Tags: python, pandas

The original dataframe `df` is:

```
     type month
0       a     1
1       b     1
2       c     1
3       e     5
4       a     5
5       c     5
6       b     9
7       e     9
8       a     9
9       e     9
10      a     1
11      a     1
```

Notice that the `month` is arranged in successive segments and repeated periodically. The size of the segments is not always the same. I would like to add a column `num`, for each successive month, renumbered from 0 again. The order of the original sequence should not be changed. The expected output should be:

```
     type month num
0       a     1   0
1       b     1   1
2       c     1   2
3       e     5   0
4       a     5   1
5       c     5   2
6       b     9   0
7       e     9   1
8       a     9   2
9       e     9   3
10      a     1   0
11      a     1   1
```

I can't use `groupby` since the values of `month` are repeated but separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we create the `groups` with checking if the next row is equal to the previous row with `Series.shift` and then `cumsum` the booleans.

Then we groupby on the groups and use `cumcount`

```
grps = df['month'].ne(df['month'].shift()).cumsum()
df['num'] = df.groupby(grps).cumcount()

   type  month  num
0     a      1    0
1     b      1    1
2     c      1    2
3     e      5    0
4     a      5    1
5     c      5    2
6     b      9    0
7     e      9    1
8     a      9    2
9     e      9    3
10    a      1    0
11    a      1    1
```

Comment: OMG...I know that the key factor to solve this question is to find the changing index of month. Thank you!!!!